# Create normally distributed variables with a defined correlation in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to create a data frame in R, with a set of variables that are normally distributed. Firstly, we only create the data frame with the following variables:

```
RootCause <- rnorm(500, 0, 9)
OtherThing <- rnorm(500, 0, 9)
Errors <- rnorm(500, 0, 4)

df <- data.frame(RootCuase, OtherThing, Errors)
```

In the second part, we're asked to redo the above, but with a defined correlation between RootCause and OtherThing of 0.5. I have tried reading through a couple of pages and articles explaining correlation commands in R, but I am afraid I am struggling with comprehending it.

Answer (score 3):

## Easy answer

Draw another random variable `OmittedVar` and add it to the other variables:

```
    n <- 1000
    OmittedVar <- rnorm(n, 0, 9)
    RootCause <- rnorm(n, 0, 9) + OmittedVar
    OtherThing <- rnorm(n, 0, 9) + OmittedVar
    Errors <- rnorm(n, 0, 4)

    cor(RootCause, OtherThing)
    [1] 0.4942716
```

## Other answer: use multivariate normal function from MASS package:

But you have to define the variance/covariance matrix that gives you the correlation you like (the `Sigma` argument here):

```
d <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = n, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(9, 4.5, 4.5, 9), nrow = 2, ncol = 2), tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)
cor(d[,1], d[,2])
[1] 0.5114698
```

### Note:

Getting a correlation other than 0.5 depends on the process; if you want to change it from `0.5`, you'll change the details (from adding `1 * OmittedVar` in the first strat or changing `Sigma` in the second strat). But you'll have to look up details on variance rulse of the normal distribution.

Comment: Someone added a comment suggesting you can force the empirical correlation to be exactly 0.5 by adding the `empirical = TRUE` argument to the `mvrnorm` function. Otherwise the empirical correlation will be a random variable with mean 0.5 (e.g., not exactly 0.5 in your simulation).